Wget websites， but click ‘index.html’ shows nothing but pictures
How can I download a website to local system, which may use javascript to show the entire content?
The local txt file should be used to extract data. I get the entire file, but why I cannot see the page offline?  Can this problem be solved using wget or some other Python libs?
wget --mirror --convert-links --adjust-extension --page-requisites --span-hosts -nd -k -P./LOCAL --default-page=test.html 'url' 

I use this code to download a websites to local system, but when I open the 'index.html' I can not see any texts or buttons. I CTRL+S the websites and see something in file management's preview, but I open the 'index.html', and get the same page as the last method.
I am sure that my Chrome does not forbid javascript
I want to use the local website to extract data and save it to csv, the first step is downloading it .

You're just downloading the HTML of the site. I would assume you also need to download the CSS, JS and all images. This is what CTRL+S will do for you automatically. You'll need to do it all yourself when you use wget

Headless browser is a more modern approach, qv.

If the pages uses javascript to display content, then you'll need to run that javascript or similar to download the content.   Seems like an XY problem.   Your end result might be better achieved by calling the same end points that the site calls rather than loading the page's HTML.

@RoryMcCrossan I can download these css， js and fonts by using the code below , but it does not work 。 The html from ctrl s way is 700kb , but wget's is 2 kb

Consider what fdomn-m said! Don't try to download the page, instead check where it loads its data from and use the same endpoints to load the data yourself.

You might have the issue that the browser treats local files, even in the same directory, not as "same origin" and thus refuses loading/execution.
